# Infinite image scrolling with instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to integrate a simple slider that scrolls to the latest 20 images from an instagram account on a website. The image implementaion via instafeed.js is working, but the scrolling won't work. I used a third-party jquery based animation for this too, but I can't get it working with the loaded insta images.

The first thing that is not working, is the automated scrolling. Sometimes it works, but only in chrome's debugging mode.

The second thing is, that the slideshow does not loop. It should repeat when the last image scrolls in.

I have uploaded the files here: [Files as download](http://veltinator.de/issue.zip)

I would be so happy, if you can help me with this problems. They are driving me crazy :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting a small timeout to allow the page to finish running your other scripts before starting the scroll.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#instascroller").scrollForever();
},1000);
```

This code is in init.js It's just a small wrapper where you already call scollForever().

Testing your provided example in chrome I was unable to reproduce the bug where the slideshow doesn't loop. It is working fine for me.

Comment: I already tried that with the timeout, but kinda everything I tried caused a another bug :D

It works for me with that now too. Thank you!